# Bash - Checking each index of an array for empty values

Tags: arrays, bash, quoting

With the following code I wish to check each index in an array for a null value, an empty string, or a string containing just white space. However it is not working.

```
test=( "apple" "orange" " ")
for i in ${test[@]};
do
    if [ -z "$i" ]; then
        echo "Oh no!"
    fi
done
```

It never enters the if block. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A space isn't empty, also you need to quote `${test[@]}` as it will currently strip out whitespace and empty values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of errors in your script

1. Un-quoted array expansion `for i in ${test[@]};`, during which the element with just spaces is just ignored by shell
2. and `-z` option would just check for empty string and not a string with spaces

You needed to have,

```
test=( "apple" "orange" " ")
for i in "${test[@]}";
do
    # Replacing single-spaces with empty
    if [ -z "${i// }" ]; then
        echo "Oh no!"
    fi
done
```

The `bash` parameter-expansion syntax `${MYSTRING//in/by}` (or) `${MYSTRING//in}` is greedy in a way it replaces all occurrences. In your case, replacing all whites-spaces by nothing (null-string), so that you can match the empty string by `-z`

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use an empty string - not space when checking with `-z` . Enclose `${array[@]}` with `""` while looping.

```
test=( "apple" "orange" "")
for i in "${test[@]}";
do
    if [[ -z "$i" ]]; then
        echo "Oh no!"
    fi
done
```

Comment: What if I wish to check for both empty string and white space?